# Reprojection of shapefile in QGIS 3.8

Tags: qgis-3

I'm using QGIS 3.8 (the latest version) and I want to reproject a shapefile from WGS84 to North America Conformal Conic. This shapefile contains locations of the stations (points). However, I spent many times to do that, but it does not work because the reprojected shapefile showed me the stations in a single lines. In ArcMap, it was easier. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: This is not enough information for us to understand what went wrong. Please [edit] your question and explain exactly what steps you took to reproject your shapefile. Does your original shapefile display the station points correctly? Screenshots would help.

Comment: Have you done the reprojection 'on the fly' through properties -> CRS, or have you exported the vector layer and saved it with the new projection (as per this [tutorial](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html))?